# trying to get latest record from the data in sql

Tags: sql, max, record

I am trying to get the latest record using max in my query.
Every week we have entries for 400 outlets and when I tried using Max, it was giving me only today's records, which was like only 90.
I am looking for a 400 output for each outlet and it has to be latest record, even if it is this week or last week's data.

Comment: Could you show your current SQL query and what you have tried?

Comment: Check this tutorial out, it may help us help you :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

please see my query:

Select a.*, b.outletnbr
from table a
left join table b on a.id = b.id
where date in (select max(date) from table a)

Answer (score 0):

as i understand the question (to get last record for every `id`) you need something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id) a.*, b.outletnbr
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id, date DESC;
```

Comment: i need responses of all outlets, by latest date only and no repetitions, and also joining it with table b to get the outletnbr.